# Looking for a .net core lib for RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

the https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html clients are not conpatible with .netcoreapp 1.0. Does anybody know if one exists?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably already know this but in case that not check out [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/issues/148).
They have an experimental [dotnetcore](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/tree/dotnetcore) branch. Maybe you should give it a try.